# Installing Python's Pandas under Mountain Lion via easy_install

Tags: python, gcc, pandas, easy-install

I am having trouble with installing Python's Pandas Library on my new MacBookPro running Mountain Lion.

I tried installing Pandas via easy_install.  However, there is obviously an issue with easy_install and gcc (see error message I get below). It seems that easy_install cannot find the gcc-compiler that it apparently requires (gcc-4.0). I did everything exactly as I did on my previous MacBook running Snow Leopard where everything worked fine. I'm more of an applied person and not so much into programming itself, so I'd appreciate any help :-)

Here's a list of information and things I tried but didn't solve the problem:

- XCode 4.5 is installed, I also installed the Command Line Tools from within Xcode (also re-installed Xcode).
- Starting a gcc compiler in the terminal also works fine.

  Stefans-MacBook-Pro:/ Stefan$ which gcc
  /usr/bin/gcc
  Stefans-MacBook-Pro:/ Stefan$ gcc
  i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
- Is there a problem with the path settings so that when gcc is called, it is not appropriately redirected to the compiler? As I am not that experienced I don't want to start creating links without having double-checked with you...
- I suspect the problem to be more easy_install&gcc-specific than Pandas-specific as I get the same error when trying to install Cython via easy_install.

I'm a bit confused as under Snow Leopard everything worked absolutely fine.

Thanks a lot!

Here's the full error message:

```
Stefans-MacBook-Pro:~ Stefan$ sudo easy_install pandas   
Searching for pandas
Processing pandas-0.10.0.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-zr8Lfg/pandas-0.10.0/setup.cfg
Running pandas-0.10.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-zr8Lfg/pandas-0.10.0/egg-dist-tmp-N1xJeV
warning: no files found matching 'setupegg.py'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.png' found anywhere in distribution
gcc-4.0: error: unrecognized command line option '-arch'
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: The `-arch` flag is Apple specific, so it seems you are not using the shipped `gcc`. What is the output of `which gcc`?

Comment: This is the output I get: `/usr/bin/gcc` which is exactly the same as on may old MacBook.

Comment: Well on my machine it's `/Developer/usr/bin/gcc` (SL though). Check if you have `/Developer/usr/bin/gcc` on your machine, if so `chmod -x /usr/bin/gcc` to hide it temporarily - `chmod +x /usr/bin/gcc`, to restore.

Comment: I don't have the Developers-folder, but I guess that's the standard on Mountain Lion. If I hide `use/bin/gcc`, gcc comes from `/usr/local/bin/gcc` but I get exactly the same error.

Comment: @miku: They got rid of the `/Developer` thing back in Xcode 4.2 or so. Everything is now inside `/Applications/Xcode.app` instead. And `/usr/bin/gcc` is a front-end created by the Command Line Tools that points to whichever Xcode you have selected; it's the right thing.

Comment: @Stefan: You're not running `gcc` here, you're running `gcc-4.0`. Apple hasn't shipped a 4.0 in a long time. So that has to be some other installation. And whatever that other installation is, it doesn't have the Apple extensions (in particular, `-arch`). So, where did it come from, and can you uninstall it?

Comment: @Stefan: Also, do you have any third-party Python installations, especially oddly-built ones? Because it's a bit odd that it would pick `gcc-4.0` over `gcc` in the configure step…

Comment: @abarnert, Thanks for update, I a bit behind with SL I guess :|

Comment: @abarnert: Actually, I have no clue where gcc-4.0 should come from. The laptop is brand-new, I just installed some statistical/computing packages (Stata, MATLAB, R, Python). Would it be safe to simply delete the gcc-4.0 from /usr/bin/?

Comment: @Stefan: Are you sure it's in `/usr/bin`, not `/usr/local/bin`? It's generally _not_ safe to delete stuff in `/usr/bin` unless you know how it got there. Nobody but Apple should be putting things there. Of course a broken package may do so, in which case you want to fix it… but if you don't know where it came from, that could be dangerous.

Comment: @Stefan: Also, why did you install Python? 10.8 already comes with Python 2.7. And you seem to be installing into the system Python's site-packages (although it's hard to be sure). Unless you have some reason that you need a second installation, you shouldn't have one; it's going to lead to a lot of confusion.

Comment: @abarnert: I don't have any third-party Python installations, basically just Python 2.7.3, Numpy, Scipy plus some minor packages installed via easy_install.

Comment: @Stefan: I'm pretty sure Apple ships 2.7.2. So if you have 2.7.3, you _do_ have a third-party installation. If you didn't install it from python.org or Enthought or similar, could it have come with something else you installed?

Comment: Can you do `which gcc-4.0`, `which python`, `which python2.7`, `which easy_install`, `which easy_install-2.7`, `which cc`, `cc -v`, and `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @abarnert: I installed Python 2.7.3 from python.org because I simply wasn't aware of Mountain Lion being already shipped with Python 2.7. gcc-4.0 is in `usr/bin`, not in `usr/local/bin`, so I think I better keep it for now.  I'm confident that I installed the additional packages into my 2.7.3 install of Python (in the `/Library/Frameworks` folder, not in `/Library/Python`)

Comment: @Stefan: Well, you need to figure out where `gcc-4.0` came from. If you have more pressing things to do, you could temporarily rename it out of the way to get through your installs, then rename it back.

Comment: @abarnert: I'll try to figure out, where gcc-4.0 in usr/bin comes from... strangely however, gcc-4.0 is also present in the same folder on my Snow Leopard laptop where everything works out fine. One reason for installing an additional Python version from python.org is that I need Numpy and Scipy both of which will only install with a separate python.org installation. (At least I couldn't install it without having installed Python explicitly before).

Comment: @Stefan: First, I don't know who told you that `numpy` and `scipy` will only install on a separate installation. I've got them installed on my stock Python installation on half a dozen 10.7 and 10.8 boxes. Second, what version of Xcode do you have on the 10.6 box. It's been a few years since Apple shipped a gcc 4.0, but it's also been a few years since Apple shipped 10.6…

Comment: If you want the easiest full blown scientific python environment, go with enthought.com. The whole package is free for academics, a subset is free for everyone, and that subset seems to cover your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the configure script is finding `gcc-4.0` instead of `gcc`. Since Apple hasn't shipped a `gcc-4.0` in a very long time (Xcode 3.1 for 10.5, if I remember right), this can't possibly be an Apple build.

So, you have at least one gcc toolchain in addition to the on that came with Xcode/Command Line Tools. And, wherever it came from, it doesn't have the Apple extensions—in particular, the `-arch` flag.

And that's why you get:

```
gcc-4.0: error: unrecognized command line option '-arch'
```

The easiest solution is to figure out where you installed gcc-4.0 from and uninstall it.

If you don't remember installing `gcc-4.0`, there are a few possibilities:

- If you're using Homebrew, MacPorts, or Fink, it may have been installed as a prerequisite for some other package you installed. In this case, it should almost certainly be in, respectively, `/usr/local/bin`, `/opt/local/bin`, or `/sw/bin`, rather than `/usr/bin`.
- Some other package you installed may have installed `gcc-4.0` as well for some reason.

In general, having multiple gcc toolchains will lead to confusion. And the same goes for having multiple Python 2.7 installations. In both cases, just use Apple's, unless you need another one for some reason, or you really know what you're doing.

Since you said this is a new laptop you just started setting up, if you're hopelessly lost, it might be better to start over: migrate your user account and settings to a clean install, then re-install the things you need.

(While we're at it, you're generally better off using `pip` instead of `easy_install`. Do a `sudo easy_install pip`, then you can `sudo pip install pandas` and Cython and so on. Except for `pip` itself, and `readline`.)

Comment: I'll have a closer look at the issue again tonight, but at the moment it seems to me that setting up a new clean install will be the easiest thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've got Xcode already, i would just install through Macports. That will take care of all your dependencies and compilation issues. Get Macports and its as simple as:

```
sudo port install py27-pandas
```